AttributeError: 'healthcareApp' object has no attribute 'ids' to fetch data from firebase though tkinter desktop app
i want to develop the kivy app, that fetches the data at real time from firebase that is send from tkinter app. here i also used youtube tutorials but i am having issues. it is tkinter app sends data to firebase, but i am unable to get the data from firebase and gives me error "AttributeError: 'healthcareApp' object has no attribute 'ids'". in tkinter app the labels are not shown any numbers, but the send the vital sign data to firebase.
my tkinter app code
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

class RealTimeVitalSignsApp:
    def __init__(self, root, excel_file, column_name):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Real-Time Vital Signs")

        # Load Excel data
        self.df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/training data\data in XLSX format/b_1__p_id_5044545__d_2020_1_10__t_18_35.xlsx')

        cred = credentials.Certificate(
            r"C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/data-notification-71c1a-firebase-adminsdk-r3e79-8b41638df2.json")
        ###Down line use to connect the firebase database in the python
        #firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"databaseURL": "https://data-notification-71c1a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"})
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)  ##to connect firestore in the python
        self.firestore_db = firestore.client()

        # Create labels to display vital signs
        self.label_heart_rate = ttk.Label(root, text="Heart Rate: ")
        self.label_heart_rate.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Blood_pressure1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Blood pressure(systolic): ")
        self.label_Blood_pressure1.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Blood_pressure2 = ttk.Label(root, text="Blood pressure(diastolic): ")
        self.label_Blood_pressure2.pack(pady=10)

        self.label_Saturated_level = ttk.Label(root, text="Saturated level: ")
        self.label_Saturated_level.pack(pady=10)

        self.start_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Updating", command=self.update_labels)
        self.start_button.pack(pady=10)

        # Set the initial value
        self.update_index = 0

    def update_labels(self):
        # Check if there are more rows to update
        if self.update_index < len(self.df):
            # Get the value from the DataFrame
            # current_value = self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['HR']

            current_data1= {'HeartRate': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['HR']),}
            current_data2={'Blood pressure(systolic)': float(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['BP1']),}
            current_data3={'Blood pressure(diastolic)': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['BP2']),}
            current_data4={'Saturated level': int(self.df.iloc[self.update_index]['SPO2']),}
            # Add other fields as needed

            # Update the label
            self.label_heart_rate.config(text=f"HeartRate:{current_data1}")
            self.label_Blood_pressure1.config(text=f"Blood pressure(systolic):{current_data2}")
            self.label_Blood_pressure2.config(text=f"Blood pressure(diastolic): {current_data3}")
            self.label_Saturated_level.config(text=f"Saturated level:{current_data4}")

            # Increment the update index
            self.update_index += 1

            # Categorize the vital sign value
            current_data1['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signHR(current_data1['HeartRate'])
            current_data2['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signBP1(current_data2['Blood pressure(systolic)'])
            current_data3['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signBP2(current_data3['Blood pressure(diastolic)'])
            current_data4['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_signSPO2(current_data4['Saturated level'])

            self.root.after(1000, self.update_labels)

            # Send data to Firebase Cloud Firestore
            self.send_to_firestore(current_data1, current_data2, current_data3, current_data4)

        else:
            # Reset the update index when all rows are processed
            self.update_index = 0

    def categorize_vital_signHR(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value > 100:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 60 <= value <= 100:
            return "Normal"
        elif value < 60:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signBP1(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value >= 160:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 120 <= value <= 139:
            return "Normal"
        elif 140 <= value <= 159:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signBP2(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value >= 100:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 80 <= value <= 89:
            return "Normal"
        elif 90 <= value <= 99:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def categorize_vital_signSPO2(self, value):
        # Add your conditions to categorize the vital sign value
        if value < 85:
            return "Emergency"
        elif 95 <= value:
            return "Normal"
        elif 94 <= value <= 86:
            return "Alarming"
        else:
            return "Average"

    def send_to_firestore(self, data_dict1, data_dict2, data_dict3, data_dict4):
        # Replace 'patient1' with the actual patient identifier
        patient_id = 'patient1'

        # Replace 'vital_signs' with your desired collection name
        collection_ref = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id) #.document('vital_signs')

        # Add a new document with all the fields
        # collection_ref.set(data_dict)
        collection_ref.document('HeartRate').set(data_dict1)
        collection_ref.document('BloodPressureSystolic').set(data_dict2)
        collection_ref.document('BloodPressureDiastolic').set(data_dict3)
        collection_ref.document('SaturatedLevel').set(data_dict4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace 'your_excel_file.xlsx' with the path to your Excel file
    # Replace 'HeartRate' with the actual column name you want to display
    excel_file_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/training data\data in XLSX format/b_1__p_id_5044545__d_2020_1_10__t_18_35.xlsx'
    column_to_display1 = ['HR', 'BP1', 'BP2', 'SPO2']

    firebase_credential_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/data-notification-71c1a-firebase-adminsdk-r3e79-8b41638df2.json'

    # Create Tkinter root window
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Create the application
    app = RealTimeVitalSignsApp(root, excel_file_path, column_to_display1)

    # Start the Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()

########################
# vital_sign_category = self.categorize_vital_sign(current_value)
            # current_value['Category'] = self.categorize_vital_sign(current_value['HeartRate'])
            # Schedule the next update
# self.send_to_firestore(current_data)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_value,vital_sign_category)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data1)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data2)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data3)
            # self.send_to_firestore(current_data4)
########################
# # heart_rate = int(heart_rate)
        # #collection_ref = self.firestore_db.collection('patient 1').document('heartrate')
        # heart_rate = int(heart_rate)
        # Blood_pressure1 = float(Blood_pressure1)
        # Blood_pressure2 = int(Blood_pressure2)
        # Saturated_level = int(Saturated_level)
        #
        # patient_id = 'patient1'
        #
        # # Replace 'heartrate' with your desired collection name
        # # collection_ref = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('heartrate')
        # collection_ref1 = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('Heart_Rate')
        # collection_ref2 = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('Blood_pressure1')
        # collection_ref3 = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('Blood_pressure2')
        # collection_ref4 = self.firestore_db.collection(patient_id).document('Saturated_level')
        #
        # # Add a new document with the heart rate and category as fields
        # document_data1 = {'Heart Rate': heart_rate, 'Category': category}
        # document_data2 = {'Blood pressure 1': Blood_pressure1, 'Category': category}
        # document_data3 = {'Blood pressure 2': Blood_pressure2, 'Category': category}
        # document_data4 = {'Saturated level': Saturated_level, 'Category': category}
        #
        # # collection_ref.set(document_data)
        # collection_ref1.set(document_data1)
        # collection_ref2.set(document_data2)
        # collection_ref3.set(document_data3)
        # collection_ref4.set(document_data4)

my kivy app code below:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, ThreeLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget, TwoLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, initialize_app
from kivy.clock import Clock

# from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar

Window.size = (300, 500)

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    PatientOne:
    PatientTwo:
    PatientThree:
    PatientFour:
    PatientFive:
    PatientSix:
    PatientSeven:
    PatientEight:
    PatientNine:
    PatientTen:
           
<MenuScreen>:
    name:'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Home Screen'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
           
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_1'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient1'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_2'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient2'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_3'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.3}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient3'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_4'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.4}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient4'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_5'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient5'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient6'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_7'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient7'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_8'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.3}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient8'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_9'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.4}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient9'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'b_10'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'patient10'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
  

<PatientOne>:
    name:'patient1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 1'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
    MDLabel:
        id: heart_rate_label
        text: "Heart Rate: "   
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.7} 
           
    MDLabel:
        id: blood_pressure1_label
        text: "Blood Pressure (Systolic): "
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.6} 
    
    MDLabel:
        id: blood_pressure2_label
        text: "Blood Pressure (Diastolic): "
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.5} 
        
    MDLabel:
        id: saturated_level_label
        text: "Saturated Level: "
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.6,'center_y':0.4}
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
          
<PatientTwo>:
    name:'patient2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 2'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientThree>:
    name:'patient3'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 3'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientFour>:
    name:'patient4'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 4'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientFive>:
    name:'patient5'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 5'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientSix>:
    name:'patient6'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 6'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientSeven>:
    name:'patient7'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 7'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientEight>:
    name:'patient8'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 8'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            
<PatientNine>:
    name:'patient9'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 9'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                        
<PatientTen>:
    name:'patient10'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 10'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back to Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'menu'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

"""

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class PatientOne(Screen):
    pass

class PatientTwo(Screen):
    pass

class PatientThree(Screen):
    pass

class PatientFour(Screen):
    pass

class PatientFive(Screen):
    pass

class PatientSix(Screen):
    pass

class PatientSeven(Screen):
    pass

class PatientEight(Screen):
    pass

class PatientNine(Screen):
    pass

class PatientTen(Screen):
    pass




sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(PatientOne(name='patient1'))
sm.add_widget(PatientTwo(name='patient2'))
sm.add_widget(PatientThree(name='patient3'))
sm.add_widget(PatientFour(name='patient4'))
sm.add_widget(PatientFive(name='patient5'))
sm.add_widget(PatientSix(name='patient6'))
sm.add_widget(PatientSeven(name='patient7'))
sm.add_widget(PatientEight(name='patient8'))
sm.add_widget(PatientNine(name='patient9'))
sm.add_widget(PatientTen(name='patient10'))


class healthcareApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(healthcareApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Initialize Firebase
        cred = credentials.Certificate(r"C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/heart detection thesiswork/data-notification-71c1a-firebase-adminsdk-r3e79-8b41638df2.json")
        initialize_app(cred)
        self.firestore_db = firestore.client()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)

    def update_labels(self, dt):
        # Reference to the Firebase Firestore collection
        collection_ref = self.firestore_db.collection('patient1').document('vitals')

        # Retrieve the document data
        doc = collection_ref.get().to_dict()

        # Update the labels with real-time data
        if doc:
            self.ids.heart_rate_label.text = f"Heart Rate: {doc.get('HeartRate', '')}"
            self.ids.blood_pressure1_label.text = f"Blood Pressure (Systolic): {doc.get('BloodPressureSystolic', '')}"
            self.ids.blood_pressure2_label.text = f"Blood Pressure (Diastolic): {doc.get('BloodPressureDiastolic', '')}"
            self.ids.saturated_level_label.text = f"Saturated Level: {doc.get('SaturatedLevel', '')}"

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M2"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("Navigation")


healthcareApp().run()


[enter image description heenter image description herere](https://i.sstatic.net/FyAR36TV.png)
enter image description here

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The defined ids are only in the ids dictionary of the rule where they are defined. They are never in the App itself. For example the code:
<PatientOne>:
    name:'patient1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: 'Patient 1'
            elevation: 5
        Widget:
    MDLabel:
        id: heart_rate_label

defines a heart_rate_label id within the rule for the PatientOne Screen. So that id will only appear in the ids dictionary of the PatientOne instance.
To access the heart_rate_label id you can traverse the widget tree of the App down to the PatientOne Screen. Try replacing:
self.ids.heart_rate_label.text = f"Heart Rate: {doc.get('HeartRate', '')}"

with:
self.root.get_screen('PatientOne').ids.heart_rate_label.text = f"Heart Rate: {doc.get('HeartRate', '')}"


sir i have done this but cant show data in the mobile app.

review m code in your system, and see where I am mistaken, because what I guess that the code I wrote is similar to the tkinter code to send data to firebase. i am confused how to fetch the data now. please coorperate
